# Paypal Custom Link

Tags: paypal

Regarding paypal buttons, I see plenty of stuff online that talks about creating a custom button to use in place in lieu of their official buttons.

What if I skipped using a button entirely and just used its alt tag to say what the link is?

```
 <form target="_blank" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi­bin/webscr" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="">
 <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Blah blah blah"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
 <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
 <input class="alty" type="image" src="" border="0" name="submit" alt="Donation to specific project">
 <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Just realized this doesn't work in Chrome, but it does work in FF. I'm just asking, say it did work in all browsers, would this be allowed, ie, just using alt tags to make it clear that it's a link to paypal's page?

Are there are workarounds that allows you to use a word/sentence that's a link to paypal's page, short of using paypal's email link?

In case anyone asks why I'm not using paypal's email link - it's because I cannot change the email address for that that link, whereas if I use code as in above, I can change the email address so the notification can go the the right person. (there are multiple programs in one department).

Advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it in this way also . You are allowed to use your link or images to direct to the PayPal checkout page .
And as far as the above code is concerned its working fine in chrome too , just tested it out .

Comment: really? So, the code above showed `Donation to specific project` without any images? Just asking because in my Chrome, it shows a broken image link.

Comment: But thanks for letting me know that I'm allowed to use my link/images in lieu of Paypal's official buttons.

Comment: and of alt-tag too. I was really uncertain if that would be allowed. Just tested my code from above, and huh, it worked! But yesterday, it didn't! Strange. Still, just using alt-tag alone is not something that Paypal would get bugged about, right? Ok, I'll shut up now. =)